# Django: How can I show a list of values in a text input field?

Tags: python, django, forms

I have defined a Model with a ManyToManyField, and I want the field to show the values joined by spaces, for example:

```
<input type="text" name="foo" value="val1 val2 val3"/>
```

I have defined the form to use CharField to represent the multiple values:

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    foo = CharField(label='Foo')
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

Instead of showing the values separated by spaces, the value shows this instead:

```
[u'val1', u'val2', u'val3']
```

How can I override this behavior?

Comment: Is this just for displaying, or should the user be able to modify the relation with this form?

Comment: The user should be able to modify the relation.  I implemented a clean method which splits the value and validates each element, and a view which takes the cleaned input and adds the elements to the related set.

Comment: I looked at MultiWidget and MutliValueField but those seem to have too many hoops to jump through for what I'm doing.  It seems like it should be very simple...

Answer (score 0):

You have a basic misunderstanding, which is that fields themselves aren't responsible for how they're rendered. That's what [widgets](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/forms/widgets/) do.

Comment: So far I haven't found an example of a widget that does what I described above.  Looking through the code in widgets.py doesn't make it any clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally figured it out:

```
class MultiValueTextWidget(TextInput):
    def _get_value(self, value):
        return " ".join(value)

    def _format_value(self, value):
        if self.is_localized:
            return formats.localize_input(self._get_value(value))
        return self._get_value(value)
```

I had tried this earlier (before I posted the original question), but I think there was something wrong with my field declaration.  It works when I instantiate the field with the widget like this:

```
markets = CharField(widget=MultiValueTextWidget(), label='Ticker symbols')
```

For some reason I had trouble with this:

```
class Meta:
    widgets = {
        'markets': MultiValueTextWidget()
        }
```